# Authenticate users with Zimbra LDAP Server from other CentOS clients

Tags: centos, ldap, authentication, zimbra

I'am wondering that how can integrate my database,web,backup etc.. centos servers with Zimbra LDAP Server. Does it require more advanced configuration than standart ldap authentication ?

My zimbra server version is

```
[zimbra@zimbra ~]$ zmcontrol -v
Release 8.0.5_GA_5839.RHEL6_64_20130910123908 RHEL6_64 FOSS edition.
```

My LDAP Server status is

```
[zimbra@ldap ~]$ zmcontrol status
Host ldap.domain.com
    ldap                    Running
    snmp                    Running
    stats                   Running
    zmconfigd               Running
```

I already installed nss-pam-ldapd packages to my servers.

```
[root@www]# rpm -qa | grep ldap
nss-pam-ldapd-0.7.5-18.2.el6_4.x86_64
apr-util-ldap-1.3.9-3.el6_0.1.x86_64
pam_ldap-185-11.el6.x86_64
openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64
```

My /etc/nslcd.conf is

```
[root@www]# tail -n 7 /etc/nslcd.conf
uid nslcd
gid ldap
# This comment prevents repeated auto-migration of settings.
uri ldap://ldap.domain.com
base dc=domain,dc=com
binddn uid=zimbra,cn=admins,cn=zimbra
bindpw **pass**
ssl no
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
```

When i run

```
[root@www ~]# id username
id: username: No such user
```

But i am sure that username user exist on ldap server.

EDIT : When i run ldapsearch command i got all result with credentials and dn.

```
[root@www ~]# ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.domain.com:389 -w **pass** -D uid=zimbra,cn=admins,cn=zimbra -x 'objectclass=*'

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=domain,dc=com> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: objectclass=*
# requesting: ALL
#

# domain.com
dn: dc=domain,dc=com
zimbraDomainType: local
zimbraDomainStatus: active
.
.
.
```

Comment: can you check your /etc/nsswitch.conf? I believe modern centos use sssd, not nslcd.

Answer (score 0):

If your zimbra server has multiple domains your base needs to be:

```
ou=people,dc=domain,dc=tld
```

You need to set your ldap to target users by uid

```
uid=%uid
```

Comment: How can i set my ldap to target users by uid? Can you answer it more spesific?

Comment: My mistake, you already set your uid to nscld. Try changing gid to nscld, too. Change your base as I mentioned in my answer and try again.